# Как поставить условие на время?

Tags: python, время

Если я поставлю условие на текущее время, то программа сработает, а если поставить условие на время, которое нужно подождать, то программа входит в бесконечное ожидание. Почему?

```
import time 

now = time.localtime() 

hour = int(input("Укажите час.\nВвод: "))
minute = int(input("Укажите минуту.\nВвод: "))

while True:
    if now.tm_hour == hour and now.tm_min == minute:
        print("Hello World!")
        break
```

Comment: так вы один раз время задали в `now` и теперь постоянно сверяете одни и те же переменные :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переменная `now` задана один раз и тем самым вы сверяете одно и то же бесконечно.

```
import time

hour = int(input("Укажите час.\nВвод: "))
minute = int(input("Укажите минуту.\nВвод: "))

while True:
    now = time.localtime()
    if now.tm_hour == hour and now.tm_min == minute:
        print("Hello World!")
        break
```

Однако, лучше заместо `time.localtime` использовать `datetime.now`:

```
from datetime import datetime

hour = int(input("Укажите час.\nВвод: "))
minute = int(input("Укажите минуту.\nВвод: "))

while True:
    dt = datetime.now()
    if dt.hour == hour and dt.minute == minute:
        print("Hello World!")
        break
```

Comment: А можете уточнить в ответе, почему лучше в данной задаче использовать `datetime.now`? Заранее - спасибо.

Comment: @СергейКох, модуль `time` в основном предназначен для работы с `Unix TS`, а `datetime` делает все то же самое, однако, представляет более удобный объектно-ориентированный вид. Также в `datetime` можно нормально работать с часовыми поясами.

Comment: Ещё бы `sleep` добавить, а то такой код будет жрать процессор как не в себя ))